# Firefox work offline with virtual host

Tags: apache, firefox, httpd.conf

So I have an offline website on my PC that I want to test in Firefox. I would like to do it in the offline mode.

The problem is, I have defined a virtual host for the website in httpd.conf Apache configuration file like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "D:\data\o\WebProjects\website\public"
   ServerName website
</VirtualHost>
```

When in online mode, I can go to http://website/ and test it normally. However it does not work in offline mode. Any hack around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think in offline mode FF will bother to open any TCP connection (not even so with localhost). Try opening http://127.0.0.1 in offline mode. If it fails then no chance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put the URL in hosts file?

```
127.0.0.1       localhost www.xyz.com
```

The host file, in Windows, is in *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc*, while in Linux it is usually place in */etc/hosts.conf*.